# Sass structure for angular components

Tags: css, angular, sass, structure

Our team is working on an angular-based large project and we are creating small independent components for different controls (navigation, input, textarea, table, button etc) so that they can be used independently in different projects.

We are not sure how to organize the stylesheets in this case (we are using sass that compiles to one css file for now). If all the components need to be independent and have their own separate sass file, how are we going to organize things like css inheritance, using styles from different vendor css-s (for example we use MDL).

If we write all the CSS that a particular component uses only in its own SASS file in its own directory, we are going to have many duplicate styles in different components. Is there a common solution for these kind of cases?

Thanks a lot for sharing your advice!

Comment: In my case I do in fact write independent style sheets, but I import stuff like functions, mixins and variables into the independent files. This way each component doesn't rely on other components which to me is the best way to go because then they can be re-used in other projects too.

Answer (score 4):

In a project I am working on, we have been using individual stylesheets for components, whilst also having *common* stylesheets for common elements within the application.

```
- app
    - assets
        - css
            main.scss
            buttons.scss
            forms.scss
            grid.scss
            typography.scss
        - images
        - fonts
    - components
        - component-a
            component-a.ts
            component-a.scss
        - component-b
            component-b.ts
            component-b.scss
```

Your component SASS in this instance, should only contain SASS for the component.

It would be worth it (if you haven't already) to read up on [Component Styles](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#view-encapsulation) in Angular 2.

Comment: This is also how I do it, you can have a file for form elements for example that styles all of them, such as font size, colors etc.

Comment: Thank you. In this case, if I want to use some styles inside the component's SASS, I should import the general css inside it and, for example, extend the style I want to reuse, right? In this case, won't I include some unnecessary styles inside the component's SASS as well? Is that considered to be the best practice?

Also, if I import some general styles inside different components, I am going to have a lot of duplication of the same styles inside the final compiled CSS of the page, right? Is there a way to avoid this?

Thank you.

Comment: Your component SASS should only be styles for *that component*. If your component needs to vary in style then I would create configuration classes within your component.

    .component { color: white; }
    .component--red { color: red; }

Comment: Thanks for sharing your advice.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to split scss into to part.

1. Variable definitions, functions and mixins (everything that is reusable)
2. All styles that are global. Such as font-sizes, form styles, grid and so on
3. Component specific styles which can be encapsulated into the component

This way you can deliver one global stylesheet for the application and encapsulate the component specific style.
By separating everything that is reusable (variables, functions and mixins) you can use it in styles that are only used in component scss you include into the component.

Comment: Thank you. However, as I mentioned in the comment above as well, won't I have some styles included inside the component that I do not need if I import global styles to extend some part of it inside the component's SASS file? Also, in the final compiled CSS, won't I have duplicate style definitions if I import the same global styles inside different components?

Comment: I would have duplicate styles. But styles loaded in a component only effect the html inside the component. So you can encapsulate component specific style and be sure, that it doesn't change the style of other components. And within your build process you could add this styles to your components package. And when using lazy loading you can have a smaller global style and move the component specific parts to the components and load this style only on demand together with the component.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments and research, below is the structure of the project we went with in terms of styles organization (we are using also MDL):

```
- app
    - assets
        - css
            reset.scss
            helpers.scss (some global styles)
            mdl.scss (native MDL styles)
            variables.scss (global variables)
    - components
        - component-a
            component-a.scss (will import component-a-variables.scss here)
            component-a-variables.scss (variables used only for this component)
        - component-b
            component-b.ts
            component-b.scss (will import component-b-variables.scss here)
            component-b-variables.scss (variables used only for this component)
```